# SUMIFS with nested AND, OR, and inequalities

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

The following formula doesn't work:

```
=SUMIFS(JOBS_NUMBER,JOB_TYPE,$A10,MONTH_CLAIMED,(AND(OR(">"&$H$7,"="& $H$7), OR("<"&$J$7,"=" &$J$7))),SECTOR, "=Residential")
```

I'm trying to sum the number of jobs:

- if the range JOB_TYPE matches,
- if the MONTH_CLAIMED is greater than or equal to `H7` (which contains the start of the fiscal year) AND less than or equal to `J7` (which is the end of the fiscal year), and
- the SECTOR must be `Residential`.

The embedded And(OR(inequalities are the problem, since the following test formula returns `0`:

```
=SUMIF(Z8, AND(OR(">"&$H$7,"="&$H$7),OR("<"&$J$7,"="&$J$7)),Y8)
```

where `Z8` is a date between `H7` and `J7`, and `Y8` is `1`.

I'd appreciate help with correcting the syntax or possible alternatives to accomplish the same task.

Comment: The sumif where I sum a single cell was only to test that it was not the named ranges, but the syntax of the inequalities that was wrong. The actual formula I was trying to fix is at the top. I'll fix my question to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming,the required Job Type is in A10, and you wish to sum relevant values in ColumnY rows 7 to 12 inclusive, this may help:

```
=SUMIFS(Y7:Y12,JOB_TYPE,A10,Z7:Z12,">="&H7,Z7:Z12,"<="&J7,Sector,"Residential")
```

However the above does assume compatibility between MONTH_CLAIMED and dates elsewhere.

Comment: Worked when I replaced `Y7:Y12` with the named range JOB_TYPE in the example, and replaced `Z7:Z12` with named range MONTH_CLAIMED. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
=sumifs(Y8, Z8, ">="&$H$7, Z8, "<="&$J$7)
```

No need for the AND / OR

Hope this helps